# Brightness Slider Not working in Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 22.04, brightness, nvidia-geforce

I have intel CPU and NVIDIA GPU and have tried Every Solution posted on net and nothing works for me. Tried editing the NVIDIA and AMD file in xorg.cong.d and installed software to change the brightness but brightness doesn't change.Is there any manual way to do it.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1474363/edit) to provide more information about exactly what you tried. Also post your exact hardware details.